# Windows Update under windows 10 - Very limited information, how to get more information?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I've installed Windows 10 on a PC, and I've noticed that the Windows Update process seems a lot like a black box, there is no information on how long updates will take if the PC needs to be restarted for an update to be installed etc.

Is there any way of getting a bit more information about whats going on with the updates outside of the "Settings app"?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer here is No.

The long answer:

The Windows Update section in the 'settings' app gives a decent amount of information.

1. The number of updates and their names
2. The progress bars for 'update downloading' and 'update installing'
3. Notification as to whether you system needs to restart after installing (since it checks afterwards if any important areas have been updated, which will require a restart).

An update will **always** need to be 'installed', this just how the system works.

If you are getting any less information than what I have highlighted above, then there is a problem with your system.